# Delete cookie working outside the function but not when it is in

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I've tried to delete cookie and set the new one from function (inside of cookie_approve) and it's not working but if  I put it outside the function it deletes the cookie.

What I mean: there is a div on a page. User click the button (onClick event) inside this div. Cookie will be created. Next time when user will come back (or refresh the site) this div will not appear.

This is my code:

```
//create cookie
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10000 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
} else var expires = "";
document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}

//read cookie val
function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
}
return null;
}

//change cookie date  
function eraseCookie()
{
document.cookie = 'cookie_approve=; expires='+new Date(0).toUTCString() +'; path=/';
}

//hide div after click, create cookie with val=1 for 7 days
function cookie_approve(){
eraseCookie();
createCookie("cookie_approve", 1, 7);

document.getElementById('cookie_show_info').style.display = "none";
}

if(readCookie("cookie_approve") == undefined){
createCookie("cookie_approve", 0, 7);
}

function show_cookie(){
    document.getElementById('cookies_rules').style.display = "block";
}

function hide_cookie(){
document.getElementById('cookies_rules').style.display = "none";
}

document.write('<div id="cookie_show_info" style="display: none;">Text <div id="cookies_rules">Cookie rules</div>    <a onClick="cookie_approve()">Button</a></div>');

if(readCookie("cookie_approve") == 0){
document.getElementById("cookie_show_info").style.display = "block";
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: what's exactly not working, creating or deleting? How does your createCookie() function looks like?

Comment: createCookie function You have on top of my code.
As I mention before: I try to delete cookie and recreate it with new val = 1 using onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Your eraseCookie() function looks a bit strange

try those maybe:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

source: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Nope, not working. As I said before: I clicking on button link (with onclick event) but the cookie isn't changing. Val = 0.
It looks like the cookie can't be change using onClick event. Is it possible ?

Comment: could you set up a fiddle? Does the button anything else? Have you set preventDefault attributes?

Comment: Everything you can find on http://zabezpieczstrone.pl . The pink div on the bottom of the page :)
Akceptuj is the button (hiding and creating cookie with val = 1).
What I've noticed : debuger found something like this : TypeError: document.cookie.split is not a function

Comment: I can't find the problem with your code, but you are using jquery, have you tried the jQuery cookie functions?

Comment: You also include your cookie script two times: at the top and the bottom. Try to remove all other javascript, maybe there is a conflict...

Comment: Ok, I've found what was the problem. The Google Analytics has broken my script. Everything is working fine now :) Thank you all for your support.